# Having ScrollView.contentSize issues not able to scroll properly on Top, Left, Right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, contentsize

Having a Child-View inside Scroll- View and getting issues in Scroll on Top, Left, Right ?

Code for adding Pinch & Zoom in Child Sub-View

```
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingerPinch = [[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self
                                                 action:@selector(twoFingerPinch:)]
                                                autorelease];

    [_childView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerPinch];
```

Method For Pinch & Zoom a Child-View

```
- (void)twoFingerPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    //NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    // you can implement any int/float value in context of what scale you want to zoom in or out
    _childView.transform = transform;

    _scrollView.contentSize =
    CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width,_childView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Is there any issues in Scroll-View ContentSize setting ?

Here is my Code

[Code Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccaavc56sonp10q/AlertView%203.zip)

Thank you

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more about the view hierarchy?

Comment: Have you read the Scroll View Programming Guide? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html  It describes how to setup scroll view for zooming and scrolling.

Comment: @Chancy SuperView -> ScrollView --> ChildView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Set _scrollview frame **size** and _childview frame **size** same:

//Frame for scrollview 56, 92, 196, 408.

```
_scrollView.delegate = self;

_scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
_scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10;

_childView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 196, 408)];

_childView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

[_scrollView addSubview:_childView];

 [_scrollView setContentSize:_childView.frame.size];
```

and implement this delegate

```
 - (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
    return _childView;
  }
```

Also check your auto resizing flag in XIB. it is set to bottom margin.

Comment: Not working :(. Left and Top scrolling is not working I am not able to see the left and top corners of childView.

Comment: Check your scrollview's & its superview frame. Can you upload the screenshot if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing scrollView's width to contentsize. You should pass childView's width.

_scrollView.contentSize =
    CGSizeMake(**_chilView**.frame.size.width,_childView.frame.size.height);

Comment: Not working :(. Left and Top scrolling is not working I am not able to see the left and top corners of childView.

Answer (score 0):

You should not get `_childView.frame.size.height` after `CGAffineTransform`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331786/behaviour-of-cgaffinetransformmakescale-with-cgrect-and-with-uiview) explain it well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of your current scenario.

But after iOS5, UIScrollView has following :-

```
// `pinchGestureRecognizer` will return nil when zooming is disabled.
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGestureRecognizer NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

From the description, it appears that if you set these-

```
@property(nonatomic) float minimumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0
@property(nonatomic) float maximumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0. must be > minimum zoom scale to enable zooming
```

You can simply enable zooming using these properties. And zoom-in & zoom-out should work for you automatically without having to implement your own UIGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

I Have removed all the code and changes with below code I have done very stupid mistake :)

```
   _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_childView.frame.size.width, _childView.frame.size.height);
        _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
        _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        _scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        _scrollView.delegate = self;


    - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //    NSLog(@"View - %@\n",_childView);
        return _childView;
    }
```

Thanx @Mavericks

:)